# StreamWriter limit in C# in text file

Tags: c#, text-files, limit, streamwriter

I have an array list which contains 100 lines.
When i try to export it into a text file (txt), the output is only 84 lines and it stops in the middle of the 84th line.
When I looked at the file size it showed exactly sharp 4.00KB as if there is some kind of a limit to the stream writer. I tried using different parameters etc. but it kept happening.

Here is the code:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);

StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
ArrayList chartList = GetChart(maintNode);

foreach (var line in chartList)
{
    sw.WriteLine(line);
}

fs.Close();
Console.WriteLine("Done");
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Use the `using`-statement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to call `StreamWriter.Flush` or set `StreamWriter.AutoFlush` to true. That said, if you use `using` statment, everything should work fine.

```
using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
{
    ArrayList chartList = GetChart(maintNode);    
    foreach (var line in chartList)
    {
        sw.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

Using statement calls `Dispose` which will flush the buffer to the `FileStream` and also closes the file stream. So you don't need to close it manually.

Then I recommend `List<T>` over `ArrayList`. `ArrayList` shouldn't be used, it is not type safe and should be avoided if you're in .Net2.0 or greater.

Also consider using [File.WriteAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealllines%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, so that you don't need these many lines of code. Everything is managed by `WriteAllLines` method itself.

Comment: OK I will use this tip for next time. Thanks :)

Comment: The 'using' comment fixed my problems. I didn't change a single line of code other than adding the using keyword and curly braces, and now everything works great!