# StreamWriter 64512 character limitation

Tags: c#, string, stringbuilder, streamwriter

I am using stringbuilder to collect some strings in my code. At the of that code my stringbuilder has more than 100000 chars.

But writeline function writes only first 64512 chars in stringBuilder. When I debugged the code I saw that stringbuilder is able to return all of 100000 chars, but streamwriter can't handle these all charachters. My stringbuilder variable is `sbPmml` in the code below.

```
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(txtDP.Text + "\\" + txtPmmlName.Text + ".txt");
file.WriteLine(sbPmml.ToString());
```

How can I print all these chars to file via stringbuilder wihtout spliting the stringbuilder a few pieces?

Comment: Try to close your stream.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25222674/streamwriter-limit-in-c-sharp-in-text-file)?

Comment: Thanks @qxg. It worked for me!

Comment: teşekkürler ;) @Badiparmagi

Comment: @neverwinter rica ederim :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I added the code below. It worked for me

```
file.AutoFlush = true;
```

Comment: Hmm, you are not closing the stream for some reason.  That can't be very healthy.