# Write a huge string in XDocument.SetAttributeValue

Tags: c#, xml, out-of-memory, linq-to-xml

I have a large `StringBuilder` (~140MB) that I need to write in an XML attribute. I'm using `XDocument` to handle XML manipulation.

When trying to write the `string` to the XAttribute, I get a `System.OutOfMemoryException` (because I need to call `StringBuilder.ToString()`, which I suppose loads the whole string in memory).

```
var length = value.RawArtifact.Content.Length;
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
int pos = 0;
while (pos < length - 1000)
{
    b.Append(BitConverter.ToString(value.RawArtifact.Content, pos, 1000).Replace("-", ""));
    pos += 1000;
}
b.Append(BitConverter.ToString(value.RawArtifact.Content, pos)).Replace("-", "");
var buffer = b.ToString(); // This throws an exception
myAttribute.SetAttributeValue("my-attribute", buffer);
```

I could not find any overload for `SetAttributeValue` that would take something like a `StreamReader` or anything, so I feel kind of stuck right now.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Not answering your question, but writing a string of 140MB into a single attribute sounds like a bad idea. Even having an XML of this size doesn't sound good to me.

Comment: It is a terrible idea. I know .. But unfortunately this decision was not up to me .. In the end, however, the final result is still *theoretically* XML-compliant, so aside from the abhorrent size it represents, I'm not doing something that unusual.

Comment: If you check the [reference source for `XAttribute`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.Xml.Linq/src/System/Xml/Linq/XAttribute.cs#L36) you will see that `XAttribute` has `internal string value;` so there is no way to use a `StringBuilder` or `StreamReader` as a value.

Comment: This doesn't precisely answer your question, but if you were to write your XML with `XmlWriter` you could write the attribute value in chunks using `XmlWriter.WriteChars()`.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/InBShg for a demo.

Comment: Thanks, that's actually a nifty idea ! I'll have to be creative because I'm injecting my do-everything-related-to-XML class, but unless someone is quicker, I'll post what I come up with as an answer.

Comment: If you are modifying an existing XML file, you might consider a streaming transformation along the lines of [Combining the XmlReader and XmlWriter classes for simple streaming transformations](https://web.archive.org/web/20160214201608/https://blogs.msdn.com/b/mfussell/archive/2005/02/12/371546.aspx) and answers that use it including [File size restriction or limitation in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12500278/3744182), [Edit a large XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48575462/3744182) and [Automating replacing tables from external files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28903486/3744182).

Comment: At one point I wrote an answer suggesting use of `XmlWriter.SwiteChars()` -- then realized you were using `XDocument` not `XmlWriter` so I deleted the answer.  Should I undelete it?

Comment: I'd say yes. What I'll do is instead of directly writing those huge string through `SetAttributeValue`, I'll write them at the last moment by using a custom implementation of `XmlWriter`, and injecting that writer in `XDocument.Save(XmlWriter writer)`. But this will probably be largely inspired by your proposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the [reference source for `XAttribute`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.Xml.Linq/src/System/Xml/Linq/XAttribute.cs#L36) you will see that `XAttribute` has `internal string value;` so there is no way to use a `StringBuilder` or `StreamReader` as a value.

Instead, you might consider a streaming approach where you inject the required attribute into the XML stream as you write out your `XDocument`. If you do, you can combine [`XmlWriter.WriteStartAttribute()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwriter.writestartattribute?view=net-5.0) with [`XmlWriter.WriteChars()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwriter.writechars?view=net-5.0) to write your huge attribute value in chunks.  The [`WriteChars()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwriter.writechars?view=net-5.0#remarks) method:

> can be used to write large amounts of text one buffer at a time.

And so is designed for exactly this situation.  There are two basic ways you might implement streaming injection of an attribute value:

1. Use the algorithm from *[Combining the XmlReader and XmlWriter classes for simple streaming transformations](https://web.archive.org/web/20160214201608/https://blogs.msdn.com/b/mfussell/archive/2005/02/12/371546.aspx)* by Mark Fussell and inject the attribute while streaming from an `XmlReader` returned by [`XDocument.CreateReader()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xnode.createreader?view=net-5.0) to an `XmlWriter`.

   For some examples, see *[File size restriction or limitation in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1297585/3744182)*, *[Edit a large XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48574631/3744182)* and *[Automating replacing tables from external files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28891440/3744182)*.
2. Subclass `XmlWriter` itself and inject the attribute as your target element is being written.

   For an example see *[Custom xmlWriter to skip a certain element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32149676/3744182)*.

Adopting the second approach, first create the following extension methods:

```
public static partial class XmlExtensions
{
    public static void WriteAttribute(this XmlWriter writer, string localName, IEnumerable<(char [] Buffer, int Length)> valueSegments) =>
        WriteAttribute(writer, null, localName, null, valueSegments);
        
    public static void WriteAttribute(this XmlWriter writer, string localName, string namespaceUri, IEnumerable<(char [] Buffer, int Length)> valueSegments) =>
        WriteAttribute(writer, null, localName, namespaceUri, valueSegments);
    
    public static void WriteAttribute(this XmlWriter writer, string prefix, string localName, string namespaceUri, IEnumerable<(char [] Buffer, int Length)> valueSegments)
    {
        writer.WriteStartAttribute(prefix, localName, namespaceUri);
        char [] surrogateBuffer = null;

        // According to the docs, surrogate pairs cannot be split across calls to WriteChars():
        // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwriter.writechars?view=net-5.0#remarks
        // So if the last character of a segment is a high surrogate, buffer it and write it with the first character of the next buffer.
        foreach (var segment in valueSegments)
        {
            if (segment.Length < 1)
                continue;
            int start = 0;
            if (surrogateBuffer != null && surrogateBuffer[0] != '\0')
            {
                surrogateBuffer[1] = segment.Buffer[start++];
                writer.WriteChars(surrogateBuffer, 0, 2);
                surrogateBuffer[0] = surrogateBuffer[1] = '\0';
            }
            int count = segment.Length - start;
            if (count > 0 && char.IsHighSurrogate(segment.Buffer[segment.Length-1]))
            {
                (surrogateBuffer = surrogateBuffer ?? new char[2])[0] = segment.Buffer[segment.Length-1];
                count--;
            }
            writer.WriteChars(segment.Buffer, start, count);
        }
        writer.WriteEndAttribute();
        if (surrogateBuffer != null && surrogateBuffer[0] != '\0')
            throw new XmlException(string.Format("Unterminated surrogate pair {0}", surrogateBuffer[0]));
    }
}

public static class ByteExtensions
{
    // Copied from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14333437
    // By https://stackoverflow.com/users/445517/codesinchaos
    // To https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa
    // And modified to populate a char span rather than return a string.
    public static void ByteToHexBitFiddle(ReadOnlySpan<byte> bytes, Span<char> c)
    {
        if (c.Length < 2* bytes.Length)
            throw new ArgumentException("c.Length < 2* bytes.Length");
        int b;
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++) {
            b = bytes[i] >> 4;
            c[i * 2] = (char)(55 + b + (((b-10)>>31)&-7));
            b = bytes[i] & 0xF;
            c[i * 2 + 1] = (char)(55 + b + (((b-10)>>31)&-7));
        }
    }
    
    public static IEnumerable<(char [] segment, int length)> GetHexCharSegments(ReadOnlyMemory<byte> bytes, int chunkSize = 1000)
    {
        var buffer = new char[2*chunkSize];
        var length = bytes.Length;
        int pos = 0;
        while (pos < length - chunkSize)
        {
            ByteExtensions.ByteToHexBitFiddle(bytes.Span.Slice(pos, chunkSize), buffer);
            yield return (buffer, buffer.Length);
            pos += chunkSize;
        }
        ByteExtensions.ByteToHexBitFiddle(bytes.Span.Slice(pos), buffer);
        yield return (buffer, 2*(length - pos));
    }
}
```

Next, subclass `XmlWriter` as follows:

```
public class ElementEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public XName Element { get; init; }
    public Stack<XName> ElementStack { get; init; }
}

public class NotifyingXmlWriter : XmlWriterProxy
{
    readonly Stack<XName> elements = new Stack<XName>();

    public NotifyingXmlWriter(XmlWriter baseWriter) : base(baseWriter) { }

    public event EventHandler<ElementEventArgs> OnElementStarted;
    public event EventHandler<ElementEventArgs> OnElementEnded;

    public override void WriteStartElement(string prefix, string localName, string ns)
    {
        base.WriteStartElement(prefix, localName, ns);
        var name = XName.Get(localName, ns);
        elements.Push(name);
        OnElementStarted?.Invoke(this, new ElementEventArgs { Element = name, ElementStack = elements });
    }

    public override void WriteEndElement()
    {
        base.WriteEndElement();
        var name = elements.Pop(); // Pop after base.WriteEndElement() lets the base class throw an exception on a stack error.
        OnElementEnded?.Invoke(this, new ElementEventArgs { Element = name, ElementStack = elements });
    }
}

public class XmlWriterProxy : XmlWriter
{
    // Taken from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32150990/3744182
    // by https://stackoverflow.com/users/3744182/dbc
    // To https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32149676/custom-xmlwriter-to-skip-a-certain-element
    // NOTE: async methods not implemented
    readonly XmlWriter baseWriter;

    public XmlWriterProxy(XmlWriter baseWriter) => this.baseWriter = baseWriter ?? throw new ArgumentNullException();

    protected virtual bool IsSuspended { get { return false; } }

    public override void Close() => baseWriter.Close();

    public override void Flush() => baseWriter.Flush();

    public override string LookupPrefix(string ns) => baseWriter.LookupPrefix(ns);

    public override void WriteBase64(byte[] buffer, int index, int count)
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteBase64(buffer, index, count);
    }

    public override void WriteCData(string text)
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteCData(text);
    }

    public override void WriteCharEntity(char ch)
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteCharEntity(ch);
    }

    public override void WriteChars(char[] buffer, int index, int count)
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteChars(buffer, index, count);
    }

    public override void WriteComment(string text)
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteComment(text);
    }

    public override void WriteDocType(string name, string pubid, string sysid, string subset)
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteDocType(name, pubid, sysid, subset);
    }

    public override void WriteEndAttribute()
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteEndAttribute();
    }

    public override void WriteEndDocument()
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteEndDocument();
    }

    public override void WriteEndElement()
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteEndElement();
    }

    public override void WriteEntityRef(string name)
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteEntityRef(name);
    }

    public override void WriteFullEndElement()
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteFullEndElement();
    }

    public override void WriteProcessingInstruction(string name, string text)
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteProcessingInstruction(name, text);
    }

    public override void WriteRaw(string data)
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteRaw(data);
    }

    public override void WriteRaw(char[] buffer, int index, int count)
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteRaw(buffer, index, count);
    }

    public override void WriteStartAttribute(string prefix, string localName, string ns)
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteStartAttribute(prefix, localName, ns);
    }

    public override void WriteStartDocument(bool standalone) => baseWriter.WriteStartDocument(standalone);

    public override void WriteStartDocument() => baseWriter.WriteStartDocument();

    public override void WriteStartElement(string prefix, string localName, string ns)
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteStartElement(prefix, localName, ns);
    }

    public override WriteState WriteState => baseWriter.WriteState;

    public override void WriteString(string text)
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteString(text);
    }

    public override void WriteSurrogateCharEntity(char lowChar, char highChar)
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteSurrogateCharEntity(lowChar, highChar);
    }

    public override void WriteWhitespace(string ws)
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteWhitespace(ws);
    }
}
```

And now you will be able to do something like:

```
string fileName = @"Question68941254.xml"; // or whatever

XNamespace targetNamespace = "";
XName targetName = targetNamespace + "TheNode";

using (var textWriter = new StreamWriter(fileName))
using (var innerXmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true }))
using (var xmlWriter = new NotifyingXmlWriter(innerXmlWriter))
{
    xmlWriter.OnElementStarted += (o, e) =>
    {
        if (e.Element == targetName)
        {
            // Add the attribute with the byte hex value to the target element.
            ((XmlWriter)o).WriteAttribute("TheAttribute", ByteExtensions.GetHexCharSegments(value.RawArtifact.Content.AsMemory()));
        }
    };
    xdocument.WriteTo(xmlWriter);
}
```

Where `xdocument` is, of course, some `XDocument` that you are trying to populate and add an attribute `TheAttribute` to a node `TheNode`.

Notes:

- Since your code shows you are populating the `StringBuilder` by converting a large byte array to a large hex string buffer, I eliminated the intermediate `StringBuilder` and wrote the byte array directly in chunks.

  If you do need to write the contents of some `StringBuilder b` in chunks, use

  ```
  public static partial class StringBuilderExtensions
  {
      public static IEnumerable<(char [] segment, int length)> GetSegments(this StringBuilder sb, int bufferSize = 1024)
      {
          var buffer = new char[bufferSize];
          for (int i = 0; i < sb.Length; i += buffer.Length)
          {
              int length = Math.Min(buffer.Length, sb.Length - i);
              sb.CopyTo(i, buffer, length);
              yield return (buffer, length);
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  And pass `b.GetSegments()` to `XmlExtensions.WriteAttribute()`.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OSEGQN) with the result:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
  <SomeOtherNode>some value</SomeOtherNode>
  <TheNode TheAttribute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
    <foo></foo>the node value</TheNode>
  <AnotherNode>another value</AnotherNode>
</Root>
```